# Angular ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError with inline edit table

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have a table where it calls a child component called modal, modal component has two buttons save and cancel that are used for inline edit. I know I have to use "ChangeDetectorRef" but I cant figure out how to use the event "ngAfterViewInit" wit my code

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked. Previous value: 'disableEditSaveButton: false'.
>   Current value: 'disableEditSaveButton: true'.

**dashboard.HTML**

```
 <p-table #dt  [value]="iToDoList" dataKey="id"  [paginator]="true" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,50,100]"
                             [rows]="10">

                        <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Comment</th>
                                <th>Action</th>

                            </tr>
                            </ng-template>
                            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-row>  
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{row.id}}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div  *ngIf="!row.isEditable">{{row.comment}}</div>
                                        <div *ngIf="row.isEditable">
                                            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="row.comment">
                                            <span *ngIf="isEmpty(row.comment)" style="color:crimson">Required</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div>
                                            <modal  [disableEditSaveButton]='disableSaveButton' (open)="onOpen(row)" [showModal]="!row.isEditable"  (selectedRow)="onSelectedRow(row)" (cancelEdit)="onCancelEdit(row)"></modal>
                                        </div>
                                        <!--<button (click)="editRow(row)">Edit</button>-->
                                    </td>
                                    <td>                                <button (click)="save(row)">Save</button></td>
                                </tr>
                            </ng-template>

                    </p-table>
```

**dashboard.compnent** (this is causing ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError)

```
 isEmpty(input) {
        if (input.replace(/\s/g, '') === "") {

            this.disableSaveButton = true;
        }
        else {
            this.disableSaveButton = false;
       }
       // this.cdr.detectChanges();

        return input.replace(/\s/g, '') === "";
    }
```

**modal.html**

```
   <div *ngIf='!showModal'>
        <button type="button" class="btn-xs btn-primary" (click)="onSave()" [disabled]='disableEditSaveButton'>Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn-xs btn-orange" (click)="onCancelEdit()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
```

**modal.component**

```
@Input() disableEditSaveButton: boolean = false;
```

******************UPDATE*************************************************************************

the browser it is still throwing ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

**Component**

```
   isEmpty(input) {

        this.cdr.detach();

        if (input.replace(/\s/g, '') === "") {

            this.disableSaveButton = true;
        }
        else {
            this.disableSaveButton = false;
        }
        // this.cdr.detectChanges();

        // restart change detection for this view
        this.cdr.reattach();

        return input.replace(/\s/g, '') === "";
    }
```

Comment: https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

Comment: I saw this article and i tried doing ngAfterViewInit() {
       
        
       
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }                                                                                                                    it still it does not work because, I am setting the child input not within the  ngAfterViewInit. Not sure how would I do that, if the child values needs to be set in the "isEmpty" method

Comment: I used setTimeout, it worked but very slow...I need a better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so here comes another approach.

Analysing your code I could see that

```
this.disableSaveButton === isEmpty(row.comment)
```

This means that, if `isEmpty(row.comment)` is true, `this.disableSaveButton` is true too and the other way round.

So why don't you directly use the result of `isEmpty(row.comment)` instead of storing it into `this.disableSaveButton` ? Doing this you have no changing expression as the first true or false will also be the last.

Please, try it this way:

```
<modal  [disableEditSaveButton]='isEmpty(row.comment)' 
        (open)="onOpen(row)" 
        [showModal]="!row.isEditable"  
        (selectedRow)="onSelectedRow(row)" 
        (cancelEdit)="onCancelEdit(row)">
</modal>
```

And if you don't need `this.disableSaveButton` for other purposes than your modal dialogue, which means you don't need it at all now, you could shrink the size of your method to this, without changing it's logical outcome.

```
isEmpty(input) {
    return input.replace(/\s/g, '') === "";
}
```

Comment: I reckon I found a way to set the boolean value of `[disableEditSaveButton]`only once. Thus, you shouldn't face the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` again.

Comment: wow , it worked ..very simple but also smart way ...thanks a lot..learned something valuable from you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
isEmpty(input) {
    // stop change detection for this view
    this.cdr.detach(); 

    if (input.replace(/\s/g, '') === "") {

        this.disableSaveButton = true;
    }
    else {
        this.disableSaveButton = false;
   }
   // this.cdr.detectChanges();

    // restart change detection for this view
    this.cdr.reattach(); 

    return input.replace(/\s/g, '') === "";
}
```

Comment: Updated , my code..it is working but in the browser it is still throwing ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError. I rather resolve the issue by not getting an error in the browser, just to make sure this error does not cause other issues when I continue developing my apps, any thoughts!